# Breaking a line inside a span using Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm well aware that span is an inline element and by making a separate span and simply using `display:block` on it would be the solution in most other cases. Mine is a bit more complicated since my code is tangled up in Javascript & semi-PHP code. So here's what I'm facing:

This part of the code is used in the template file (.tpl):

```
<p id="reduction_amount" {if !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'amount' || $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval ==0} style="display:none"{/if}>
   {strip}
    <span id="reduction_amount_display">
     {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'amount' && $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval !=0}
     SAVE {convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction|floatval-$productPrice|floatval}
     {/if}
    </span>
   {/strip}
</p>
```

..And this part inside a .js file:

```
if (combination.specific_price.reduction_type == 'amount') {
  $('#reduction_amount_display').html('SAVE ' + formatCurrency(discountValue, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
  $('#reduction_amount').show();
}
```

This works perfectly and this is how it looks like currently:

[image]

(note: the `<p>` element has a fixed width and height)

The thing is, I'd like to give a line break after the "SAVE" part and be able to style the amount shown with a bigger font size. Demonstration:

[image]

This could be, as I mentioned above, achieved by separating the two with two other spans and stylizing them to how I want it to look. However, as my knowledge in Javascript is quite limited I do not know the correct way to insert a span. I tried several ways, for example adding `html += '<span class="blabla">'` right before `formatCurrency` and a closing tag after the paranthesis but this kinda messed up everything in the design for some reason. I also tried without using `html +=` and plainly with quotes and the same thing happened. What solution is there for this? It does not necessarily have to be Javascript code. It could be a CSS or an HTML solution as well.

EDIT:

Using `<br>` is unfortunately not plausible since I wouldn't be able to stylize the amount shown separately. Also, using that tag makes a huge gap that the amount goes way out of (overflows) the `<p>` element.

Comment: can you not just add <br /> after "save"? Then an <span class='foo'>$10</span>

Then use css to apply your new style to class foo?

Comment: @user3739842 Not quite, as then I wouldn't be able to stylize the amount separately. Also it kinda gets messed up. The gap between amount and "SAVE"  gets way too big (they do not stick).

Comment: you can change the height of the <br/> in css also

Comment: @user3739842 The issue with not being able to stylize the amount still remains though.

Comment: See my edit in original comment, you can append a class and then target that in css

Comment: @user3739842 Inserting a span inside the Javascript code is kinda the problem here. I'm not quite sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the dollar value in an element created by jQuery using [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), and style it accordingly with a given class.

```js
var amount = $('#reduction_amount_display');

amount.html('SAVE ');

amount.append('<div class="style-amount">$10</div>');
```

```css
.style-amount {
  font-size:32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="reduction_amount_display">

</p>
```

Comment: Should I place your code after the if statement? Also would this be correct: `amount.append('<div class="style-amount">' + formatCurrency(discountValue, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank) '</div>');` Since $10 is not a fixed amount and it varies depending on what is set in the back office.

Comment: Your questions can both be answered with a `yes`. The fixed number was only put in for demonstration purposes since we don't have the `formatCurrency()` function provided to us. Your if statement will control the provided jQuery code just as it is currently for you.